# Symfony2 Sonata Admin Bundle - field listing corresponding custom values

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

My Sonata CRUD listing page works correctly but **i would like to display the corresponding value between by entity value and an array coming from my parameters.yml**: (it's nicer to display the label instead of the key..)

I have an entity USER with a categoriesType field having the 'cat_1' value.
This is the value displayed in the listing (so.. it's ugly)

But in my sonata listing page, i would like to display a nicer value "Category 1" as set in my parameters.yml.

*Question:*

How can i display "Category 1" instead of "cat_1"  in the listing?
Is there any possibility to replace/map values with those in my parameters.yml ?

```
categories:
    cat_1:
        title: Category 1
        template: xxx.html.twig
    cat_2:
        title: Category 2
        template: ggg.html.twig
    cat_3:
        title: 'Category 3
        template: zzz.html.twig
```

Service:

```
<service id="etna.form.type.categories" class="Etna\FrameworkBundle\Form\Type\CategoriesType">
    <argument>%categories%</argument>
    <tag name="form.type" alias="categories" />
</service>
```

Form type:

```
namespace Etna\FrameworkBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CategoriesType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var array */
    protected $categories;

    /**
     * @param array $categories
     */
    public function __construct(array $categories)
    {
        $titles = array_map(function($categories) {
           return $categories['title'];
        }, $categories);

        $this->categories = $titles;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'choices' => $this->categories,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string|\Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'categories';
    }
}


protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('name', 'string', array('label' => 'Nom'))
        ->add('expression', 'string', array('label' => 'Expression'))
        ->add('categoriesType', 'categories', array('label' => 'Nom'))
        ->add('enabled', null, array('label' => 'Activé'))
    ;
}
```